# Correct way to share by reference to threads in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, reference, pass-by-reference

I have written a simple single-threaded Simulated Annealing algorithm in C#.

One of the steps is to update the best known solution and corresponding cost, whenever such a solution is discovered.

Since Simulated Annealing is a random local search, it makes sense to run separate searches on all available cores of the CPU. In this search, I wish to have a shared best known solution and corresponding cost. Occasionally, when no good solutions have been found for some time, the algorithm will return to the best known solution and resume the search from there. I want all threads to return to the global best known solution.

I know I can probably create a separate class and object that holds this value, and I know this will definitely work, but this seems a little cumbersome to me. I suspect that the `ref` keyword win C# will work in this case, but I have never used this keyword before, so I'm unsure what will happen. Normally I would set up a test case to see for myself, but due to the nature of the threads, and the highly unpredictable nature of the algorithm, it's very difficult for me to be sure what's going on and to confirm that it's correct.

So:

```
public Solution MultiThreadedSimulatedAnnealing()
{
  Solution bestKnownSolution;
  double bestKnownSolutionCost;

  // ...

  Thread[] threads = new Thread[Environment.ProcessorCount];

  for (int i = 0; i < threads.Length; i++)
    threads[i] = new Thread((ThreadStart)(() =>
    {
      multiThreadedSAThread(ref bestKnownSolution, ref bestKnownSolutionCost);
    }));

  foreach (Thread t in threads)
    t.Start();

  foreach (Thread t in threads)
    t.Join();

  return bestKnownSolution;
}
```

calls the threads:

```
private void multiThreadedSAThread(ref Solution bestKnownSolution, ref double bestKnownSolutionCost)
{
  // ...

  if (cost < bestKnownSolutionCost)
  {
    bestKnownSolution = solution;
    bestKnownSolutionCost = cost;
  }

  // ...
}
```

Will the above method work the way I intend? i.e. the code in the child threads will check and update the object stored in the calling function, and the calling function will return the best solution overall from all threads; as in there is only one copy of the best known solution and cost, shared between all child threads and parent?

(Yes, I know that the threads could while checking and/or overwriting the best cost at the same time, producing unpredictable results. I will pass an object to lock to be sure this doesn't happen; I just didn't want to overcomplicate the above example)

Thank you.

Comment: It would work, but the cost might be higher than just calculating local "best" solutions for each thread and then choosing the minimal one (depends on how often you're going to lock for accessing shared variables inside each thread).

Comment: If one thread moves in a fruitless direction for a long time, then the thread is essentially wasted. That is why I want to share the current best known solution.

Answer (score 0):

Well, without synchronization this is clearly incorrect as you pointed out yourself. When you add a consistent locking strategy to this, it will work fine.

There's not much difference between referencing a location through an object reference or through a `ref` (which is a "managed pointer" under the hood).

From a code quality standpoint packaging up those two values into a small DTO class seems like a better way to go. Cleans up the `ref` clutter and the duplication.

I also want to point out that the code is more awkward than needed due to usage of `Thread`. With tasks this would be cleaner.

Comment: Can I `lock` the `ref Solution BestKnownSolution` in the child threads? I was going to just create a new empty `object` in the parent thread to lock in the children for synchronisation. I know that would work, but it would be better if I can lock the `Solution`.

Comment: There's not just one solution but many. Makes no sense to lock there. You need to lock on the same object. It's best practice to create a fresh lock object.